# Video breakIn, breakOut Using SIP

Tags: java, android, video, chat, sip

I'm going to build a video chat application. And I need to build video call using phone number (without build third party application) and call breakout, breakin concept. I have tried with Twilio and Tokbox to achieve my goal. But as I feel they have not providing a function what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This is a recommendation question, and as such is off-topic here. Please read [ask] to get a better idea of what sort of questions work well on Stack Overflow.